# First letter of Words to UpperCase

Tags: javascript

I am making my debut with coding and i got stuck with a problem. I have to turn the First letter of a string toUpperCase.
Can someone please guide me ?
e.g : the quick fox ---> The Quick Fox.

here is my code :

```js
function convertFirstLetterOfWordsToUpperCase(phrase){
    phrase = phrase.split("");
    console.log(mot);
    phrase[0] = phrase[0].toUpperCase();
    for(var i = 1; i <= phrase.length; i++){
     if(phrase[i] == ""){
      i++;
      phrase[i] = phrase[i].toUpperCase();
     }
    }
    phrase = phrase.join("");
    console.log(mot);
}
convertFirstLetterOfWordsToUpperCase("the quick fox");
```

here is the display : The quick fox.
 Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `mot` ?

Comment: Well, if you want to show it in UI then would be better to use css `text-transform`, if it's needed in code for some reason, then use `slice` to split the string on 2 parts and then concatenate it back using `toUpperCase` on the first part. You can't change strings in JavaScript, they are immutable, you have to create a new string each time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please [**search**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+capitalize+word) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: the main problem is that you aren't `return`ing anything form the function. Try `return phrase` at the bottom of it

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're trying to detect spaces in between your words using:

```
if (phrase[i] == "") {
```

But instead, when you split based on `""`, your spaces are not empty strings, they are strings with spaces (`" "`), and so you should check against that instead:

```
if (phrase[i] === " ") {
```

See example below:

```js
function convertFirstLetterOfWordsToUpperCase(phrase) {
  phrase = phrase.split("");
  phrase[0] = phrase[0].toUpperCase();
  for (var i = 1; i <= phrase.length; i++) {
    if (phrase[i] === " ") {
      i++;
      phrase[i] = phrase[i].toUpperCase();
    }
  }
  return phrase.join("");
}
console.log(convertFirstLetterOfWordsToUpperCase("the quick fox"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with css or javascript as follows :

```
function capitalize(string) {
    return string.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(text){
        return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```